# Chrome keeps using https for my site, safari and firefox work fine

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

My site works fine on safari and firefox yet chrome insists on using https for all of my requests/resources. I can't figure out why.

Any ideas on why this might be happening. I don't have any extensions and I just deleted and reinstalled chrome using "appCleaner" (mac).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that [HSTS](https://www.chromium.org/hsts) is turned off for your site.

   Open `chrome://net-internals` and select "HSTS" from top left dropdown. Enter your domain under "Delete domain" section and press Delete button. Check again, no restart is required.
2. Try to clear browser data completely from Settings - Privacy - Clear Browsing Data.
3. Make sure (again) that you do not have any problematic extensions installed. You can create another profile and test again.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with using an outdated WooCommerce and Chrome Version 44.0.2403.89 (Latest version). It was forcing https for some reason. I am not sure if this is your issue, but I just updated WooCommere and it fixed it for me.